# Mysql takes up to 50% cpu after aborting DELETE query

Tags: mysql, crash, cpu-usage, sql-delete

I have problem I have never met before.
I was clearing yesterday clients db and table with stats of visits had 15GB of data, so I decided to delete all rows older than 1 Feb, because we have all that data stored in daily stats and there's no need to keep those old single stats.

I tried to run `DELETE FROM sv WHERE datetime < ?` (index on datetime) and `DELETE FROM sv WHERE id < ?` (primary index on id), but both queries where too slow, took more than 15 mins. So I have just aborted those queries by Ctrl+C.

Then I thought better idea would be copying table structure and February rows and remove old table, but today **I found out that mysql process on server is running up to 50% cpu usage** with normal traffic on our site.

After moving sv table out of database folder (myIsam table) **usage is still up to 50%**.

First I thought that table must have been corrupted, but phpmyadmin does not show it marked as crashed.

How I can debug this one? What have happened there?

Comment: You might want to ask it on http://dba.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your system is likely re-indexing the entire table as a result of the killed query.  If it was in a transaction in INNODB, you are also having the system rebuild the table then recreating the index.

I would look at iostat and look for disk contention.

Comment: How can I stop this recreation? I moved that table to temp dir, so what's really being recreated if there are no files on their place? For now I want to copy there table with structure only, because this website needs to be running now.